# Use Azure Migrate to migrate machines into dev test lab

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs, azure-migrate

We currently have a VMWare Lab on site.  We would like to use Azure Migrate to migrate the VMs and put them in a DevTest lab.  Is there any way to do this short of taking images once they are in Azure and then re-create them in the lab?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a similar scenario is discussed in detail in this case study: [Migrate an on-premises dev/test environment to Azure DevTest Labs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/migrate/azure-best-practices/contoso-migration-devtest-to-labs) based on the Cloud Adoption Framework and considers two approaches to migration. You can check what fits better depending on your migration goals.